# Black box appears behind character when moving in pygame, how to make it disappear?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to move a character left and right on the screen, and to do this it will be painted and erased every time. Despite the background of characters being transparent, there is a black box the size of the image visible behind it, following as it goes. It doesn't leave a train, but more acts like the character you are moving. How do I fix this? Here's my player code and the game code.

## Player:

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self,Scr,cx,cy,speed,bcolor):
        self.screen = Scr
        self.surf = pygame.image.load('player.png')
        self.surf = pygame.transform.scale(self.surf, (160, 200))
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = cx
        self.rect.y = 510
        self.speed = 30
        self.bc = bcolor

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.surf,self.rect)
        pygame.display.update([self.rect])

    def undraw(self):
        surf = self.surf.copy()
        surf.fill(self.bc)
        self.screen.blit(surf,self.rect)
        pygame.display.update([self.rect])

    def move(self,mv):
        self.undraw()
        if mv == 'd' and self.rect.bottom < WHT:
            self.rect.top += self.speed
        if mv == 'u' and self.rect.top > 0:
            self.rect.top -= self.speed
        if mv == 'l' and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.rect.left -= self.speed
        if mv == 'r' and self.rect.right < WWD:
            self.rect.right += self.speed
        self.draw()
        pygame.display.update()

    def jump(self,top,left):
        self.undraw()
        self.rect.top = top
        self.rect.left = left
        self.draw()
        pygame.display.update()
```

## Game:

```
class EggDrop:

def __init__(self,Scr):

    pygame.display.update()
    #pygame.mixer.music.load('background.mid')
    #pygame.mixer.music.play(-1,0.0)
    #self.Mplay = True
    self.Player = Player(Scr,WWD//2,WHT//2,6,BLACK)
    Scr.blit(BG, (0, 0))
    self.Scr = Scr

def togglePlayer(self):
    if self.Pvis:
        self.Player.undraw()
    else:
        self.Player.draw()
    self.Pvis = not self.Pvis
```

## Main loop

```
def run(self):
    STOP = False
    while not STOP:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                STOP = True
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                    self.Player.move('l')
                if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                    self.Player.move('r')
                #if event.key == K_RETURN:
            if event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == ord('q'):
                    STOP = True
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    STOP = True
                if event.key == ord('x'):
                    top = random.randint(0, WHT - self.Player.rect.height)
                    left = random.randint(0, WWD - self.Player.rect.width)
                    self.Player.jump(top,left)
                if event.key == ord('m'):
                    self.toggleMusic()
        self.Scr.blit(BG, (0, 0))
        #self.Player.draw()

    pygame.mixer.music.stop()

Display = pygame.display.set_mode((WWD,WHT),0,0)
pygame.display.set_caption('Egg Drop V.1')


OpeningScreen(Display)

g = EggDrop(Display)
g.run()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

When using a .png with transparency, call `convert_alpha` on the `Surface` after loading it.

From [`pygame.image.load`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load)

> For alpha transparency, like in .png images use the convert_alpha() method after loading so that the image has per pixel transparency.